# Extend dictionary without duplicate values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

This seemed like an easy issue, but I'm racking my brain to solve it without throwing any errors.

I'm updating the code for my Open Source Project [WordHoard](https://pypi.org/project/wordhoard/).

I'm adding a new feature, which is the part of speech category for the word being search.  This piece works great.  The issue is with the in-memory cache.

I need to add the part of speech category to the dictionary associated with this cache.

Adding it the first time works with the line:

> temporary_dict_definition[word] = [pos_category, values]

Attempting to extend the dictionary with new definitions isn't working.

On the initial update I get this:

> {'mother': ['noun', ["a person's own mother"]]}

When I try to extend the values I get this:

> {'mother': ['noun', ["a person's own mother"], 'a female parent', 'a woman who has given birth to a child (also used as a term of address to your mother).', 'female person who has borne children']}

This format causes problems where I try to extract content from it later.

Is there a way to update this dictionary to look like this:

> {'mother': ['noun', ["a person's own mother", 'a female parent', 'a woman who has given birth to a child (also used as a term of address to your mother).', 'female person who has borne children'}]}

*How do I solve this issue?*

Below is my current code that isn't extending the values for the dictionary correctly.

```
temporary_dict_definition: Dict[str, List[str]] = {}


def cache_definition(word: str) -> Tuple[bool, Optional[List[str]]]:
    try:
        values = temporary_dict_definition[word]
    except KeyError:
        return False, None
    else:
        return True, values


def insert_word_cache_definition(word: str, pos_category: str, values: Union[str, List[str]]) -> None:
    if word in temporary_dict_definition:
        deduplicated_values = set(values) - set(temporary_dict_definition.get(word)[1])
        print(deduplicated_values)
        if temporary_dict_definition.get(word)[0] == pos_category:
            temporary_dict_definition[word].extend(deduplicated_values)
    else:
        temporary_dict_definition[word] = [pos_category, values]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in the insertion function, here:

```py
temporary_dict_definition[word].extend(deduplicated_values)
```

You are extending the outer list with the deduplicated values, instead of the inner list. To remedy this, you should try to access the inner list when extending, as you do in the line above.

The below functions seem to do the job, but bear in mind some structural changes to the cache have been made too, to make the algorithms easier to write.

```py
from typing import Dict, Optional, Set, Tuple


cache: Dict[str, Dict[str, Set[str]]] = {}


def add_to_cache(item: str, pos_category: str, definitions: Set[str]) -> None:
    if item in cache:
        if pos_category in cache[item]:
            cache[item][pos_category] += definitions
            return
        cache[item][pos_category] = definitions
        return
    cache[item] = {pos_category: definitions}
    

def get_from_cache(item: str) -> Tuple[bool, Optional[str]]:
    success = (retrieved := cache.get(item)) is not None
    return success, retrieved


if __name__ == "__main__":  # Example driver code
    add_to_cache("Walk", "Verb", {"Travelling by foot.", "Traversing."})
    add_to_cache("Walk", "Noun", {"A recommended route to travel on.", })
    print(get_from_cache("Walk"))
    print(get_from_cache("Not in cache!"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  It almost works perfectly.   The issue now is processing the `retrieved` value correctly in another block of code.   I have to do this `list(check_cache[1].keys())[0]` and this `list(check_cache[1].values()))`, which works, but seems a little off.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex
Bear in mind a single word can be both a noun and verb (as in the example), and so `list(check_cache[1].keys())[0]` only returns the first word type it could be.

Instead, try using `check_cache[1].items()`. You can cast this to a python list, or iterate through it with `for word_type, definitions in check_cache[1].items():`. Hope this helps!

Comment: In my code it can only be one POS tag until I redesign the code to support more POS tag capabilities.

Comment: Thanks again for the assistance.  ---- **Side Note:**  I had to redo some of the Static typing in other sections of my code to handle the changes within the caching code.

Comment: No worries. I would still stick to using `check_cache[1].items()`. Then you can use `check_cache[1].items()[0]` if you're **certain** there will only be POS tag, which will give a tuple containing the POS tag, and the set of definitions.